# Instant bounty question

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a bounty on a day-old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51555/how-to-set-a-bounty-on-a-day-old-question)

Hi,

I want to ask a question and need to allot bounty points to it immediately. Can this feature be added? This may happen as I do not want to wait on questions to be answered at its own pace. I understand Stack overflow answers come in blitz speed for famous tags like Java, C#. But some other tags gives answer in their own time. I just want to accelerate that process (I am even ready to throw bunch of bounty points from my reputation)

Thanks.

Comment: What tags? The response is pretty good well into the middle-low popularity regime.

Comment: @dmckee : ruby-on-rails is the tag. I am sure it will get answered if I throw some bounty points to it. It has been 25 minutes since I asked and I am refreshing hoping an answer will come, but only in vain :(

Comment: Yeah, I found [the question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696772/need-help-in-timezone-in-rails-activerecord). Not a ruby guy, myself, but in the worst case can't you extract the parts of the record, fix the one that is bothering you and rebuild? Not elegant, but workable until something better comes along...