# Expedited bounty

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat)

I can understand not being allowed to issue a bounty immediately, but once in a while it feels like you just have to (deadlines, imminent loss of sanity, lack of interest in your subject, etc). If you feel like you have to present a bounty immediately, why not have an "expedited bounty" fee or fine of an additional 25 rep points (or half the rep points you're offering).  That way most people will still wait the 2 days but if it's urgent you don't have to wait.

My apologies if this has been asked before (like here: [Instant bounty question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64314/instant-bounty-question))  but I figure the addition of a fee  or fine makes the question unique (or at least I haven't seen it yet).

Comment: [The Office](http://originalmetalsigns.co.uk/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/8/0/80042_lack_of_planning_1.jpg)...

Comment: Not necessarily lack of planning :P just getting stumped by an issue.

Comment: Patience is a virtue. And answers tend to come very quickly to a good question - no need for bounties. What makes you think that issuing a bounty immediately will give you more/better answers?

Comment: @Oded isn't that the point of bounties? more/better/faster.

Comment: Actually "faster" is not one of the bounty goals.

Comment: No, it isn't. It is to give your question more _exposure_. And if you want more/better/faster make sure you ask a good question with enough details etc... Yes, the bounty is an _incentive_ as well - to give more answers and better ones than the others, but, frankly, the quality of answers _without_ bounties is rather high already.

Comment: @Oded and the exposure is for what? :) To get more/better answers.

Comment: sorry i wrote my reply before you edited yours.

Comment: well if anyone can delete this question, you guys have made your point.

Answer (score 8):

No.

Stack Overflow does not have "fees" and such things.

If something is SO (pun intended) urgent, just go hire a programmer. :)

Comment: It does in a way. It costs you points to set up a bounty or downvote.

Comment: Yes but starting a fee system will cause influx of other requests, e.g. why not fee to force only high-rep members to answer? Why not fee to cast "super downvote"? It never ends.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, my friend, but limits like that protect the site against flooders, spammers and people that are just too lazy to search before asking (please note that I'm not saying this is your case).

Comment: that's fair enough, it's just that reputation is not "free" you have to earn it somehow.  Anyhow, my question is getting hammered right now so clearly I'm in the wrong :).