# Isn't time consuming questioning in sites of SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Experts suggest that before you ask a question follow the following faithfully :
**READ how to ask**

**READ FAQs for stack exchange**

Then Search for the site, lookup it's domain..

Search then Research then search..

To Avoid duplicates..

*Actually no keywords of the same question would match perfectly*

**It could be a long fruitless search..**
Then wait for down votes only until then it's closed.

And then you have major job to be done
**FORMATTING YOUR QUESTION**
Making it attractive place to attract experts 
Attaching link,  pictures of your code or etc..,  highlighting major points using bold, italics.. 
Ah! 
 **IT CONSUMES 75% OF THE TIME WE DEVOTE TO QUESTION IN SE.. 
15% for reading the answer and researching on that question further. 
IS THIS USER FRIENDLY..**
IF YES,
**STILL TIME IS PRECIOUS..** AND FOR A PARTICULAR ANSWER WE COULD RATHER DEVOTE READIND MORE BOOKS RELATED TO IT AND GOOGLE IT and we have many more options..

I know SE have attracted many users over years but this may be a possible reason why new users (by it l mean those who want to learn and they're premature to share knowledge,  so questioning is a only option for them) devote lesser and lesser time.. 
**All i mean things are becoming more complicated by reading and research on the rules of SE.. Reading the pages with n no. of answers.. AND researching on the fact how to write a question in SE rather the question itself.**
P. S: No offense to any users of SE.

Comment: Downvoters: lt was just a discussion.

Comment: see also: [An “urgent” tag for questions that need answers within minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6513/165773)

Comment: Are you sure you need to use so many **bold** and CAPITAL letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, asking a question takes a lot less effort than you're imagining it does. You just have to:

- Read [the tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if it's your first time or you need a reminder of the rules
- Attempt to solve your problem to the best of your ability
- Search as thoroughly as possible for duplicates

Then clearly show your problem, all relevant details, and what you've already done to solve your problem. If you do all that, it should be well received and hopefully receive an answer, though none are guaranteed.

> Actually no keywords of the same question would match perfectly

If you've looked far and wide and can't find a duplicate, then go ahead and ask. If it has been asked before, another user will probably point it out.

> It could be a long fruitless search..

Please remember that *you're* the one looking for a solution. If you truly need a solution to a problem, then you should be willing to spend some time researching it. Anything you don't do we have to. Nevertheless, we're happy to solve your problem *if* you've already tried yourself.

> Then wait for down votes only until then it's closed.

If the question is so bad that you're *waiting* for downvotes and closure... then you probably shouldn't have asked in the first place. If your question is good, then it shouldn't be downvoted or closed.

> And then you have major job to be done FORMATTING YOUR QUESTION

Once you become familiar with [the formatting rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), it's actually not that hard. Do your best to make it look pretty and other users can edit if needed.

> STILL TIME IS PRECIOUS.. AND FOR A PARTICULAR ANSWER WE COULD RATHER DEVOTE READIND MORE BOOKS RELATED TO IT AND GOOGLE IT and we have many more options..

Nobody's making you ask a question here. If you want to get your solution elsewhere, then *that's totally fine*. Not everyone likes Stack Exchange.

> All i mean things are becoming more complicated by reading and research on the rules of SE.. Reading the pages with n no. of answers.. AND researching on the fact how to write a question in SE rather the question itself.

Getting familiar with Stack Exchange takes some time. That's a big reason for having reputation-based privileges: more experienced users can perform more trusted actions. If you accidentally do something wrong and you didn't know, that's okay. Learn why it's wrong and avoid doing it in the future.