# Who Is Everyone?

Tags: discussion, bounties, time

After being very annoyed by the 48 hour bounty rule, preventing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67114999/14921272) from getting answers, I asked "why", got sent to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3333/981269), where I found the graph below. It shows when people do/don't ask questions at time of the UTC day.
[image]

I'm wondering, **who are the people who are answering questions between 24 and 14 UTC? Where do they live? Demographic info? I'm wondering if anyone has insights as to who these answerers are, where they are, and what they are doing that makes this graph's phenomenon happen.**

Comment: 24 UTC is 8PM atlantic time in the USA. Sounds like a great time to work on your personal projects.

Comment: How exactly does your question NOT having a bounty prevent it from answering?  The majority of the answers I have submitted, keep in mind I have hundreds of answers on my main community, were submitted before a bounty could be offered.  I actually specifically avoid questions that offer bounties.

Comment: You might find the [demographic info from the last developer survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#geography) and the [Time Zone Map](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/#!cities=1440) interesting. Of course, the survey is neither limited to nor includes all users on Stack Overflow so the actual percentages may differ.

Answer (score 19):

Eh ... you know that the majority of the world's population lives in East and Central Asia? And that their office hours are (roughly) between 0 and 14 UTC? Granted, not all of them speak English, but there's a world outside the US and EMEA.

Also, that graph is from 2009. The world has changed a lot since then (even before the pandemic), and so has Stack Exchange. [This](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1397818/answer-speed-by-question-posting-hour-absolute#graph) is the current situation (top line); most questions are asked between 9 and 18 UTC.

[image]

It's not much different from [my research from a few years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329144/4751173).

I can't help but notice that it's definitely **not** the bounty rule causing your question to have no answers yet, it's your impatience (sorry for being so blunt). That question is not even an hour old right now; we're **volunteers** and nobody is forced to answer your question. If [you're in a hurry, Stack Exchange is not the place to go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/295232); what we aim to do is to write good, comprehensive answers, and that takes time.

---

OK, this is interesting. (Or my SEDE skills fail me; it's late night here already.) I've grouped Stack Overflow questions by posting hour and checked which % of them received an answer within *x* hours. That produces [the following graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1397827/answer-speed-by-question-posting-hour-relative#graph):

[image]

If you want a quick answer, you have a slightly higher chance of getting a quick answer between 6 UTC and 22 UTC (the bottom line); at the same time, those hours have the *lowest* percentages for being answered after 24 hours (the top line). I have no idea how to interpret this ...

If you're looking for absolute numbers instead, like the graph in your question, check the top line of [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1397818/answer-speed-by-question-posting-hour-absolute#graph).

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the data, etc. to back it up.

Comment: I think that questions asked between 6 and 22 UTC get a quick response, because most people are online then. At the same time, most questions are asked as well, making it easier for a question to slip between the cracks.